# Meteor : Android apk showing white screen

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, android-emulator, apk

```
BUILD SUCCESSFULon Android Emulator          \

Total time: 2 mins 32.03 secs
Built the following apk(s): mulator          -
    /var/meteor/met-wsecom/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Using apk: /var/meteor/met-wsecom/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Package name: com.id15ripp23h390l1sizzfo
INSTALL SUCCESS on Android Emulator          /
   Starting app on Android Emulator          |              
Tailing logs for Android Emulator             
=> Started app on Android Emulator.           
I20170221-10:02:19.232(5.5)? 02-21 10:00:35.411  7748  7748 I chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I20170221-10:02:20.637(5.5)? 02-21 10:00:36.053  7748  7748 W chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
I20170221-10:02:20.637(5.5)? 02-21 10:00:37.400  7748  7748 D MeteorWebApp: Detected new bundled version, removing versions directory if it exists
I20170221-10:02:20.638(5.5)? 02-21 10:00:37.759  7748  7774 W chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
I20170221-10:02:20.638(5.5)? 02-21 10:00:41.538  7748  7748 I MeteorWebApp: Serving asset bundle with version: 8b3faaa5b6fa7637c474dd2669147eaefc505608
I20170221-10:02:20.638(5.5)? 02-21 10:00:52.066  7748  7748 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1185)] "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.", source: http://localhost:12672/cordova.js (1185)
I20170221-10:02:20.638(5.5)? 02-21 10:00:52.066  7748  7748 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1178)] "Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded", source: http://localhost:12672/cordova.js (1178)
```

Comment: What do you want ?

Comment: r u using splash screen plugin in your Project ??

Comment: No I am not using any splash screen plugin

Comment: Built apk and then signed it . Got .apk file , installed it in my android phone but thing is i am unable to see anything on screen apart from white screen. Any solution.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Built the apk, signed it, installed it but then it shows nothing. If you got a solution to your problem, kindly share

Comment: Sure. Still now no solution is there. May be because of some kind of errror in app. Shifted whole project to new one progressively(by adding modules one by one and checking for APK simulatenously).  After all these efforts APK is working fine. But don't know what was going wrong.